# Finding a substance which has a continuous gradient in refractive index

Tags: physical-chemistry, optical-properties

I need to find a substance whose refractive index is constantly changing and directly proportional to the square root of the depth. I know I'm looking for a lot, but I'd really appreciate any ideas or advice from anyone. Thanks a lot

Comment: Square root or whatever, there is no such compound. In effect, you are asking for a _metamaterial_ with peculiar properties; whether or not it can be made is a separate question.

Comment: There are commercially available optical fibres with a  gradient in refractive index, presumably lenses also, often called GRIN lenses.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely true that no such substance exists, though you won't find this property in a homogeneous substance.

It's well known that changing the concentration of solute in a solution can change the index of refraction; a concentration gradient would then provide a changing refractive index, though having this mimic a square root function would be difficult. Typically, the refractive index changes linearly with the concentration of solute, so a nonlinear function may be difficult to achieve. 
A similar approach could be applied to solids, forming a solid solution, though again there would be some difficulty in finding two compounds with similar lattice parameters that would allow to a continuous gradient between compositions to product the refractive index gradient.

Your best bet may be with polymers, where changing proportions of the monomers used could change the refractive index; organic dopants can also be used to effect* this gradient in polymers (see, e.g., Polym. Adv. Technol. **2014**, *25*, 1099). Again, the difficult part would be matching a square-root function, but you could at least have a varying gradient.

*https://xkcd.com/326/